# Reading file content based on Box Webhooks Events

Tags: box-api

I want to develop an app that listens to Box Webhooks events for a file create or upload event, and then reads the content of that newly created/uploaded file.

However, I am not able to do so because as far as I understand I need an access token to be able to read contents of a file, but the Box Webhooks [create/upload] event does not provide me with any access token.

Could you please suggest a way using which I can implement my app?

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks are kinda like a postcard.  They only give you the bare minimum of info to tell you what file has changed.  They're being sent over the wire to an unauthenticated destination, so when a webhook goes out, it can't have a lot of secret information already in it.

It's up to you to catch that webhook, look at the file-id (and potentially some other info, like the user-id) and know what user to have login and get the additional information.

If your application is server-side, and the users have signed in, then you'll already have their credentials, and you can go get the extra info.

If your application is a mobile app with no server side, then you will have to have the client make the extra API calls to get the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess for the server side apps, one can still store the userid and map it with the one given in the web hook event data. However, how can a client app do so, considering it does not store any user id from the time of app authorization? Which API calls can the client make - i.e. if it can do so - to get those details?